# Javascript in Selenium to launch a webpage not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to launch a webpage using Javascript using selenium web

It wouldn't launch the site for reason.

Trying to launch a webpage using Javascript using selenium web

It wouldn't launch the site for reason. I made sure all the packages needed to called Javascript are included.

```html
package javascriptexecution;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class JavaScriptExecution {
 private WebDriver driver;
 String baseUrl;
 private JavascriptExecutor js;

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  
  js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  
  // Maximize the browser's window
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
 
 @Test
 public void testJavaScriptExecution() throws Exception {
  
  js.executeScript("window.location = 'https://letskodeit.teachable.com/pages/practice';");
  
  // driver.get() method waits for the page to load completely before going to the next statement
  // Adding Thread.sleep() because we are opening URL using js.executeScript() and it does not wait for the page to load completely
  // If we do not add wait, then Selenium WebDriver will immediately try to find the element and it might have issues with just a little slow connection
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  // Finding element
  // WebElement textBox = driver.findElement(By.id("name"));
  WebElement textBox = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('name');");
  textBox.sendKeys("test");
 }
 
 @After
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
 }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: No error. The webpage I am trying to open  is not coming up in the browser                                                                       https://letskodeit.teachable.com/pages/practice. I even tried to open https://www.google.com. still won't that page either

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? Furthermore, which version of FirefoxDriver are you using? You need to get the right version combination between the browser and driver.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need to cast [FirefoxDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html) to JavaScriptExecutor it extends [RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) which in its turn implements [JavaScriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)
2. Using [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) is a some form of a performance anti-pattern, you should either wait until [Document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) property equals `complete` or until the WebElement you're trying to interact with becomes clickable. So consider replacing Thread.sleep() with [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class instance like:

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("name")));
   ```

   More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: Actually I am use chromewebdriver.